# How do I access fields in my class from an inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

My class looks like:

```
public class Suwak extends JFrame {
  JSlider slider;
  JLabel lblWartosc;
  static int wartosc=0;

  public Suwak() {
    event e = new event();
    slider.addChangeListener(e);
  }

  public class event implements ChangeListener {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        wartosc = slider.getValue();
        lblWartosc.setText("Wartosc:"+ wartosc);
      }
  }
}
```

I have another class `Operations` with  `method1(int wartosc)`. When I'm in that method, how do I refer to `Suwak`s member variable `wartosc` so that it can be used in inner class `event`.

I tried do this in class `Operation`:

```
Suwak slider = new Suwak();
method1(slider.slider.getValue());
```

but this only shows one variable.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Looks to me like `wartosc` is declared in the outer class.

Comment: Yes declared in outher but change in inner I want take `wartosc` from inner class event

Answer (score 1):

If I understand that correctly, you want to be able to set up a `Suwak` with a change listener (inner class) that has access to `Suwak`s member variables, and you want to be able to do this from some other class, possibly outside of `Suwak`s package.

The cleanest (imo) way is to pass a reference to your `Suwak` instance into your `event` instance when constructing it.  This preserves encapsulation; your `Operations` class doesn't have to know anything about the member variables of `Suwak` or `event`.

In this example, I'm going to rename your `event` class to `SuwakChangeListener` since `event` is a confusing name.

In your class `Suwak`:

```
static int wartosc; // Class variable
JLabel lblWartosc; // Member variable

public Suwak() {
     // Pass reference to Suwak instance into SuwakChangeListener's constructor
    SuwakChangeListener e = new SuwakChangeListener(this);
    slider.addChangeListener(e);
    System.out.println(wartosc);
}

public class SuwakChangeListener implements ChangeListener {
    Suwak instance;

    /**
      * @param suwakInstance The instance of Suwak that this change listener is working with.
      */
    SuwakChangeListener(Suwak suwakInstance) {
        // Remember the instance.
        instance = suwakInstance;
    }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
        // This accesses the class variable of Suwak.
        Suwak.wartosc = slider.getValue();
        // This accesses the member variable of instance.
        instance.lblWartosc.setText("Wartosc:"+ Suwak.wartosc);
    }
}
```

Generally, it is preferred if accessors (getters) and mutators (setters) are used, rather than direct access to the member and class variables.  But both ways work.